# Chrome like HTML Element selector or Firebug like Element Inspector in .NET Desktop Application

Tags: .net, firebug, desktop

I need to develop HTML Element selector like functionality as in Chrome web browser or Fire-bug like Inspect Element in Firefox , but in my .NET Desktop application.

My basic requirement is to provide the ability to select and/or highlight the border of the main HTML container element of user's selected ( or on mouse over as Chrome does ) area/region of the HTML page.

I need help/guidance on how to do this ? Can I add Chrome or Firefox browser control in my .NET application and some how use its own Element selector functionality ?

I know there is IE browser control that comes with .NET but I doubt it provides such functionality, rather I had some serious issues in past when I had to load Ajax based or some advance CSS3 site in it in my .NET app.

Thanks in advance.

Khan

Comment: How well to you understand the HTML DOM and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If this is either a WPF or WinForms application, you can watch the [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) events for each control. When the mouse is over your control, change the border/background/font color/whatever will get attention.  In the [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event, change the control back to the way you found it.

```
    private void myControl_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Update the control to have an orange background color.
        label1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }

    private void myControl_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Update the control to have the system default window background color.
        label1.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
    }
```

Comment: Adam as I said I had bad experience in past using .net browsercontrol so I want to avoid it. For example if I load a site in my control which has some ajax code in it and have to add click or mouseneter event on DocumentCompleted callbakc , it get called 4,5 times because DocumnetCompleted  event is raised multiple times (due to ajax code run)... So is there any other browsercontrol that I can use in my .NET application and achieve my desired functionality ?

Comment: Are you trying to create another version of the WebBrowser control?